# Installing a pfx file with C# seems different to manually installing it

Tags: c#, websocket, pfx

I have a c# program which installs a pfx file (Code below)

```
X509Certificate2 cert;
        cert = new X509Certificate2(@"myCert.pfx", "password");

        if (cert != null)
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            if (!store.Certificates.Contains(cert))
            {
                store.Add(cert);
            }
        }
```

This seems to add the cert into the correct place when I view it in the management console. However I have a websocket server in c# that will pick it out of the store and use it for its ssl connections to the browser however the browsers all fail due to not having authentication to the cert.

However if I were to install it manually (clicking the cert) and installing it to the same location everything works fine.

NOTE:It is Self-Signed

How would I fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate is self-signed, you have to use it as well for the HTTPS page that holds the javascript code connecting to the websocket, so the browser can prompt you to accept the certificate.

You can retrieve the certificate using for example:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certificate = store.Certificates[1];
store.Close();
```

And then use it for your WebSocket server. I don't know which .NET WebSocket server are you using, but [in WebSocketListener is done this way](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Enabling-WebSocket-Secure-(TLS)).

Comment: Yea i have that used in the c# server and it picks out the cert fine. The HTTPS site has a valid trusted cert. Its literally if i install the local cert via c# that it wont work. Manually installing it works fine

Comment: Have you tried to install the certificate using `StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine` ?

Comment: I shall try that. I am actually using your dll's vtortola :)

Comment: It wont let me add to that location. I tried `currentUser` and it installs but retreving the cert in the server cannot find it. seems to only find it when placed into `StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser` installing the cert manually works fine...such a pain. p.s. great work on the websocket stuff

Comment: Thanks! I will try to reproduce the issue tomorrow